# Hero Animation Library on CollectionView

Tags: swift, animation, cocoapods

https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero

In the documentation for Hero, there's an example called "Usage Example 2" where they have collectionview cells fade in with a cascade effect. However, I can't seem to get it to work in my project!

Their example code:

```
self.hero.isEnabled = true
greyView.hero.id = "skyWalker"

// collectionView is the parent view of all red cells
collectionView.hero.modifiers = [.cascade]
for cell in redCells {
    cell.hero.modifiers = [.fade, .scale(0.5)]
}
```

My current code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell")

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

        // Hero Logic
        self.navigationController?.hero.isEnabled = true
        self.hero.isEnabled = true
        self.collectionView.hero.isEnabled = true

        NetworkingService.shared.getCollectionViewItems { (items) in
            guard let items = items else { return }
            self.items = items

            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            self.collectionView.hero.modifiers = [.cascade]
            for cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells {
                cell.hero.modifiers = [.fade, .scale(0.5)]
            }
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell:MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)  as! MyCollectionViewCell
        let currentItem = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = currentItem.title

        cell.isHeroEnabled = true
        cell.heroID = "cardNum" + String(indexPath.section) + String(indexPath.row)
        cell.hero.modifiers = [.fade, .scale(0.5)]

        return cell
    }
}
```

I tried setting the hero ids and animations in multiple places but still no animations for my collectionview. Any help is appreciated! If the library isn't going to work I'd also appreciate some feedback on a way to recreate this animation without the library.

Answer (score 0):

strawn, hope not so late. I dunno there been 8 months you asked but your issuing this must probably because of you're filling your collection view with api call. If you some how get your data before screen start push transition you can get your goal like

In viewDidLoad of view controller:

```
hero.isEnabled = true
collectionView.hero.modifiers = [.cascade]
```

And in custom class of your collection view cell, could be init or first data access func of it

```
hero.modifiers = [.fade, .scale(0.5), .translate(x: 100)]
```

If your navigation transitions work success, this will work too
Hope help least someone else

Stay safe, happy coding.